# Given any path $\phi$, we can find an injective path $\psi$ with the same endpoints as $\phi$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Suppose $\phi: [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ is a continuous map. Does there exist continuous, injective $\psi : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\psi(0) = \phi(0)$ and $\psi(1) = \phi(1)$ and $Im(\psi) \subset Im(\phi)$?

Comment: Just take $\psi$ to be a straight line segment

Comment: Do you want strict inclusion of the images? Otherwise we could just use $\psi = \phi$.

Comment: @Daron What if $\phi$ is not injective?

Comment: Whoops! Wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: @cpiegore: That might not be contained in the image of $\phi$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Do you have a specific example where a line segment does not work?

Comment: @cpiegore A circular arc, for example.